# Parks in industrial areas?

Tags: cities-skylines

In this new game

are parks needed in industrial areas? do they make any benefit?

Another question I have is about garbage and incinerators, when I place them in industrial areas, I see sad faces, but industrial areas are already pollute , why? should I make them very far away?

Answer (score 6):

**No.** Parks have no apparent impact on generic industry from my testing.

[image: parks]

What I did was placed 2 little isolated groups of industry along the same road, and placed an absurd amount of parks near one group of them. Both groups upgraded more based on OTHER available services...most notably when I placed a rail station right next to them (they LOVE that).

Just placing parks didn't seen to change one group from the other group. Side note: I know offices, however, care about land value and parks can raise that.

I know that parks give little happy icons when you put them near industrial areas and incinerators give the sad faces (tying into your 2nd question), but unless there is some hidden metric that is telling one sim to go work at the "nicer" industrial building (or perhaps affecting health), they have no impact on actual performance.

Comment: This is incorrect; entertainment buildings such as parks to impart a minor benefit on even generic industry. See [my answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/209709/parks-in-industrial-areas/214431#214431) for more info.

Answer (score 3):

They have a minor benefit.

If you check out the Skylines Wiki, you can see the [effect various services have on general industry and office zones](http://www.skylineswiki.com/Zoning#Building_level). "Entertainment" buildings will affect the happiness of general industry buildings and offices.

That being said, there are more effective ways to generate happiness for those zones. Focusing on public transit, service buildings, and cargo transport (for general industry) will have a greater effect than entertainment buildings.

You can usually get general industry buildings to hit level 3 without entertainment buildings such as parks. Offices, however, can be more finicky, and it sometimes takes an entertainment building or two to push them into upgrading to level 3.